# showing same page after clicking on category?

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my code for fetching all the latest post by each category .I am facing pro in category when i clicked the category it shows the same page .

```
     $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        foreach($category_ids as $kk=> $cat_id) {

          $cat_name= query_posts( 'cat='.$cat_id.'&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=ASC&paged='.$paged);
          foreach($cat_name as $post) : setup_postdata($post);


        if (have_posts ()) :

            while (have_posts ()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
                    }
                    else {
                        ?>
                        <?php if( get_the_category_list() ) { ?><p class="alignleft"><span><?php the_category( ', ' ) ?></span></p><?php } ?>
endwhile;
endif;
```

please help 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I use this script to get the latest posts of one category:

```
    <?php query_posts('category_name=XXX&showposts=YYY'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?> &nbsp; <i> <?php the_time('l, j. F Y') ?> </i> <br>
          </a> 
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

while XXX is the actual name of the category and YYY the number of posts you want to show. I only listed the titles of the posts but of course you can add the_excerpt or the_content if you like.

Don´t know if this is what you searched for but maybe it helps you out.

Greetings, 
Lara

P.S.: Have you tried plugins like catlist?